# HyperLink Column in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have 2 columns in GridView `FirstName` and `LastName`. I want all rows in FirstName column to be in hyperlink. I have tried this but didn't work. How can I do it ?

Parser Error

```
Parser Error Message: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects 
that have a  DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not
have a DataBinding event.
```

Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomersGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />

        <asp:HyperLinkField Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with this..

```
<asp:HyperLinkField 
      DataTextField="FirstName" 
      HeaderText="First Name" 
      SortExpression="FirstName" 
      DataNavigateUrlFields="FirstNameID" 
      DataNavigateUrlFormatString="PersonDetails.aspx?FirstNameID={0}" /> //use if you want to nevigate to other page
```

Comment: I tried with this but I am not allowed to click at any field as hyperlink.Where is my mistake ?  <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="google.bg" DataTextField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" /> I want to be like "<a>...</a>".

Comment: Though i not tried and perhaps i can't understand what you want to say but if you want to nevigate google from your link then you can change DataNavigateUrlFormatString as www.google.com instead of PersonDetails.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`DataTextField` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datatextfield.aspx):

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="FirstName" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to a template field:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomersGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName">
         <asp:itemtemplate>
            <asp:HyperLinkField Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
    ...
```

Comment: I tried like this <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'
                         NavigateUrl="www.google.com" ></asp:HyperLink>        
                    </ItemTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateField>but how to create header "First Name" ?

Comment: Edited my answer so you can see how to put header text in.  FYI -- If you're using VS, you can explore the gridview wizard, data source wizard, or intellisense, and you'll learn a about your options that way.